# Selection between master and children lost (non reproducible error, datas are from database)

Tags: r, database, shiny, reactive-programming

I've created DT tables with links between master table, and child tables, which has child table etc...

I click on table master and I go from table to tables. And sometimes the initial selection is lost.

The initial goal was to have 2 database, archive and present time. I have a radio button to switch between the 2 database. So I have to put in all reactive function a function to reconnect or not to the correct chosen database.

**Is a question for stackoverflow or a bug ?**

This is for a big application.

But I have the same issue for a simple (old) application without DT and without reconnection between database.

The simple and the big Shiny applications are multi-user and each user could use multi-tab on their browser.

Thanks in advance :)

**My structure of the big application:**

**server.R**

```
database_name_decale<-"blabla_decale"
database_name_archive<-"blabla_archive"

connexion_bdd_odbc_decale_txt <- paste0('driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};server=blabla;database=',database_name_decale,';uid=xxx;pwd=xxx;')
connexion_bdd_odbc_archive_txt <- paste0('driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};server=blabla;database=',database_name_archive,';uid=xx;pwd=xx;')
...
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  react <- reactiveValues( connexion_bdd = 0) 
  observeEvent(
  c(
    input$radiob.ChoixBase
  ),
  {
   Init_cnx_bdd.fct_react (input,output,session, change_base= TRUE)

 })
...
  observeEvent(input$NavTabPanels, {
    Init_cnx_bdd.fct_react (input,output,session, change_base= FALSE)
    if (input$NavTabPanels=="My_Menu") {
...
      My_Menu_maitre.tab.fct_react (input,output,session)  
    }
  })  
...
  My_Menu_maitre.tab.fct_react <- function (input,output,session) {
...
    detail.table <-  reactive({
      Init_cnx_bdd.fct_react (input,output,session, change_base = FALSE)
      input_appelant=  input$My_Menu_maitre_rows_selected
      validate(
        need(!is.null(input_appelant) , "Select a line from master")
      )                 
      res<-  data.frame() 
      table_details <-subset( My_Menu_maitre.table()[as.integer(input_appelant), ],
                              select=c("id_num"))
      res<- detail.reqSQL.fct (react$connexion_bdd,as.data.frame(table_details))            
      return(res)
    })  
...
    sub_detail.table <-  reactive({...})
...
    sub_sub_detail.table <-  reactive({...})
...
    sub_sub_sub_detail.table <-  reactive({...})
```

With this function

```
Init_cnx_bdd.fct_react <- function (input,output,session,   change_base) {
    req(react$connexion_bdd)
    if(input$radiob.ChoixBase == "BaseActuelle")   {
      output$BaseCouranteTxt <-renderText({"Actuelle"})
      if (change_base==TRUE) {
          tryCatch(
            {
              odbcClose(react$connexion_bdd)
            },
            error=function(e) { # print("e")
              },
            warning=function(w) { # print("w")  
              }
          )
          react$connexion_bdd<-odbcDriverConnect(connexion_bdd_odbc_decale_txt)
      } else {
          tryCatch(
            {
              odbcGetInfo(react$connexion_bdd)
            },
            error=function(e) {   print("e")
              react$connexion_bdd<-odbcDriverConnect(connexion_bdd_odbc_decale_txt)
            },
            warning=function(w) {  print("w")
            }
          )
      }

}

    if(input$Technique.Connexions.radiob.ChoixBase == "BaseArchive")   {
      output$Home.Technique.BaseCouranteTxt <-renderText({"Archive"})
      if (change_base==TRUE) {
          tryCatch(
            {
              odbcClose(react$connexion_bdd)
            },
            error=function(e) {  #print("e")
            },
            warning=function(w) { # print("w")   
            }
          )
          react$connexion_bdd<-odbcDriverConnect(connexion_bdd_odbc_archive_txt)
      } else {
        tryCatch(
          {
            odbcGetInfo(react$connexion_bdd)
          },
          error=function(e) { #  print("e")
            react$connexion_bdd<-odbcDriverConnect(connexion_bdd_odbc_archive_txt)
          },
          warning=function(w) { # print("w")
          }
        )
      }

    }
}
```

**My structure of the little application**:

**server.R**

```
connexion_bdd_odbc_txt='driver={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};server=xxx;database=blabla_decale;uid=xx;pwd=xxx;'
...
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
...
table.brut<-reactive({
  connexion_bdd <- odbcDriverConnect(connexion_bdd_odbc_txt, readOnly = TRUE)  
  table<-sqlQuery(connexion_bdd, "SELECT * FROM blabla")
  odbcClose(connexion_bdd)
  table<-as.data.frame(table)

  return(table)
})
...
and other tables and reactive function, not of the DT package, and a few linked between them.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems  that I use the "anti-solution" (named by Joe Cheng in his video tutorial).

anti-solution

```
observe ({
    df<-head(cars, input$nrows)
    output$plot <- renderPlot(plot(df))
})
```

good solution

```
output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(head(cars, input$nrows))
})
```

I am going to modify my code, it is solved.

https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2262

**edit** 17/1/2018

For information: the cause of lost selections was not only the use of "anti-solution". After the correction the issue was going on again a little.

I have replaced RODBC by DBI and RStudio/odbc, and the  issue doesn't occur anymore.